# Is there a way to have a virtual dekstop for RealVNC so that the remote user can use the device at the same time as someone in person?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc, virtual-desktop

I'm looking to allow the person using a windows desktop in person to be uninterrupted when a remote user connects over RealVNC at the same time. I believe this functionality already exists natively in Apple Remote Desktop, when it detects a different user trying to connect and offers them a vitrtual dekstop. Is there any way to achieve this with Windows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ARD doesn't 'offer a virtual desktop' it is capable of simultaneous multi-user access by default. If you remote to the same user that is using it locally, you share the same screen. I know Microsoft RDC will not do this other than on Win Server, it will always log out the local user, idk how that works for VNC, but it wouldn't surprise me if it's the same. MS consider it a licensing issue, one user per license. macOS isn't licensed in the same way, so has no restriction.

Comment: @Tetsujin .. so macOS has a GUI based remote desktop option that allows more than one user at a time?  I thought macOS used VNC?  I am asking because I want to know.  (I have a macbook in addition to my other machines).  Not to be a troll.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - as far as I'm aware it is VNC-based, you can connect with any VNC app, but using their ARD app you get a whole load of additional functionality  I haven't tested whether it works the same with 'just' VNC but I think it would, as the multi user is kind of at ' license level'. You can set up users as remote only, even.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Tetsujin !  Have a great day.

Comment: To the OP @Iriley , there are other known ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.  None of these ways will be discussed on this site and you will have to find them elsewhere.